# jquery $(selector).ready() code running even if no element was matched

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this code to only run this js on certain pages.

```
$("body#action_new").ready(function() {
    console.log($("body#action_new"));
    console.log($("body#action_new").length);
    console.log("code is running");
}
```

Even though body#action_new does not exist, the code is running.

the two console.logs print out:

```
[]
0
code is running
```

What gives?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot call the `ready` except on the document, intead you can try

```
$(document).ready(function(){

if($("#action_new").size()>0){
        console.log($("body#action_new"));
        console.log($("body#action_new").length);
        console.log("code is running");
    }

});
```

As stated by @Interrobang in the comments the `.size()` method internally uses `.length` so it is advised to use `.length` to avoid the additional overhead of a function call, so the above code would look like

```
if ($("#action_new").length > 0){
```

Comment: "The .size() method is functionally equivalent to the .length property; however, the .length property is preferred because it does not have the overhead of a function call." http://api.jquery.com/size/

Answer (score 9):

You cannot call .ready() on anything but **document**. You will get undefined behavior in any other case.

> The .ready() method can only be called on a jQuery object matching the current document, so the selector can be omitted.

http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to call `ready()` on a selector. You just need this: https://github.com/Verba/jquery-readyselector